# simulate a click with a key when button is focused

Tags: javascript

I wan't to simulate a click with a key when the button is focused/active. So, if I move with tab between the buttons and press key "A", the onclick methos should be called. Bellow is my sample code.

Regards!

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).activeElement(function(e){       
    if(e.which == 13){
        //perform click on a button
    }
    });
</script>

<button type="button" onclick="alert('you clicked button 1')">button 1  </button>
<button type="button" onclick="alert('you clicked button 2')" >button 2 </button>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$('body').on("keydown", "button", function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 65)
    {
        $(this).trigger("click");
    }
});
```

<kbd>**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qfwouoxu/)**</kbd>

You may change the selector for whatever you want, like a class to all elements with the desired behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

To fire events over an element, run the following code template:

```
element.fire(eventName[, memo]);
```